# Visual studio code java date returned only as milliseconds

Tags: java, date, debugging, visual-studio-code

Background:
I have a spring boot project that clean installs fine on the command line and runs correctly within eclipse when debugging.

When using visual studio code with the java extension pack (0.6.0) and the Spring boot tools (1.6.0) and running the program in debug mode with a breakpoint on any object that contains java date as one of the variables.

The problem:
Debugging the above scenario I get the follow results when inspecting any date variable within the variables debug view.

- applicationDate: Date (id=*)

  - cdate: null
  - fastTime: 1507852800000

Every date only ever returns the millisecond value for the date.

Comment: The VS debugger should be able to do _expression evaluation_, like `application.toString()`. What you are seeing are the fields a Date, which indeed are not for the non-savants.

Comment: Make sure to read the Javadoc for whatever method(s) you're using.

Comment: It's no clear what happens just based on your description, so please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to us first. I suspect maybe you need a converter here.

Comment: https://github.com/Tiney182/dateError.

Comment: Added MVCE, when debugging the Date variable set within visual studio code I only get ![https://imgur.com/a/QfyBZiK](https://imgur.com/a/QfyBZiK).

Comment: @Tiney182 Well. It's actually a java issue. See the doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html The constructor part you will see Date(): Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond. So this is actually by design. You need to use Dateformat to convert it.

Comment: Excellent thank you for the help :)